# What happens when "pip install <package name>"

Tags: python, pip

What are the sequence of steps when we do

```
$ pip install <package name>
```

More specific questions

1. How does pip find the package?
2. Where does pip store the package?
3. How to uninstall the package?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Aman. Accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 1. How does pip find the package?

On the web, from the official repository PyPI *(Python Package Index)*. A complete list of all packages [can be found here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse).

#### 2. Where does pip store the package?

They are installed in your Python directory, depends of your OS. Search about `PYTHON_PATH/Lib/sites-packages`, you may found packages install through pip :)

#### 3. How to uninstall the package?

```
pip uninstall <package-name>
```

Comment: Ad 2: under Ubuntu 15.4 the default would be /usr/local/lib/python/site-packages

Answer (score 1):

- In the Python Package Index a.k.a. [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).
- In your Python installation's `Lib\site-packages` directory.
- Usually with `pip uninstall <package-name>`